# Word(s) for someone that pretends their misdeeds are not wrong

Tags: word-request

This word is used to define a psychological phenomenon where a person will try to use logic to believe something they don't. Such as when arguing (to themselves) that something they did is not wrong.

This word can also define someone trying to believe that things which contradict themselves don't do so.

If I am not mistaken, this word starts with the letter D.

As a psychological term, it possibly has the word "mental" in it.

(It's not rationalization)

Comment: Self-deception? Cognitive dissonance? https://www.simplypsychology.org/cognitive-dissonance.html

Comment: It's dissonance! Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad I helped! Even for native English-speakers, it's not always easy to think of the "right" word, with a half-million or so in common use. Try a thesaurus when stumped.